# turn on/off the module just for a specific website

Tags: extensions, configuration

How to turn on/off custom third party extension website specific.

From backend ***System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced*** it just return false front end output. what are other options.

Comment: try this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83260/disable-extension-in-one-of-the-store-views-that-uses-same-theme-as-others

Comment: @kothari  Actually I did same but I have 2 extensions which affects configurable products and I have conflicts for these two modules. > **Mango_Attributeswatches_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable
Magentomechanics_Grid_Block_Configurable**

Comment: Class rewrites are global, you have to solve this conflict.

Comment: @fschmengler  if class rewrite are global then if other module is dependent on first one and if it is disabled for that website then it will throw an error..

Comment: You cannot disable modules per website. The "disable module output" configuration does not actually disable the modules, it just prevents the blocks of the module from rendering.

Comment: So all the module will load for all website. Is there no way to add module for one website and other for another website.